# Переменная-ссылка и указатели как с ними работать в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, указатели, ссылки

Как получить указатель (или переменную-ссылку) на переменную Color в компоненте Image? что бы не обращаться постоянно к разным компонентам и не давать им разные цвета. Или это не возможно?

```
public class DrumManager : MonoBehaviour {
    Transform obj;
    DrumElement dr;

    void Start()
    {
        //тут более менее работает
        dr = new DrumElement(obj.GetComponent<Image>().color);
        dr.Test();
        dr.Test();
        //выводит то что "задумано", только по моему исходный цвет не меняет
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //но вот когда доходит до этого момента, значение переменой  обнуляется (т.е. rgba(0,0,0,0))
        dr.Test();
    }
}

unsafe class DrumElement
{
    public Color* col;

    public DrumElement(Color _col)
    {
        time = 0;
        transparence = 0;

        col = &_col;
        print("cool" + *col);
        print("cool111 " + *col);
        Test();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        (*col).r -= 0.1f;
            print((*col).r);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам по себе тип `Color` в Unity - это структура, об этом написано в [официальной документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html), а структуры в C# являются value type (или значимыми типами), а не ссылочными, в отличии от классов. Для ваших нужд самым логичным решением будет получить ссылку на комопнент `Image`(который как раз-таки ссылочный тип, потому что является [классом](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html)), и закэшировать ее, а для изменения вам нужно будет обращаться к вашей ссылке на `Image` и менять значние ее свойства `Color`.

В целом, кэширование компонентов в Unity это практически обязательная практика, так как методы по типу `GetComponent<T>()` довольно дорогостоящие и нужно стараться минимизировать их использование в своем проекте.

Comment: Не знал что структуры не могут быть ссылками. К слову, с указателями и ссылками я только начал разбираться) Спасибо)

Comment: @GSerge по reference type и value type советую почитать либо оф документацию (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) либо любой более или менее профессиональный справочник по c#

Comment: структуру все равно можно по ссылке передать, если использовать ref аргумент перед типом структуры при передаче в функцию.